# Google Sheets: Query With Dynamic Dates

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table in Google Sheets and I would like to create a query with dynamics dates. The structure of the table is as follows:

Col A as client_name
Col B as product
Col C as purchase_date

I tried to do this but it didn't work:

```
Query(A:B;"Select A,B Where C > '&D1&' AND C < '&E1&'")
```

D1 as initial_dynamic_date, E1 as final_dynamic_date

I would like to be able to filter by dynamic cells D1 and E1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 options:

```
=QUERY(A:B; 
 "select A,B 
  where C > &D1*1& 
    and C < &E1*1)
```

or:

```
=QUERY(A:B; 
 "select A,B 
  where C > date '&TEXT(D1; "e-m-d")&' 
    and C < date '&TEXT(E1; "e-m-d")&'")
```